# Show Hide Check boxes depending on another check boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am totally new to web development so please do not leave any negative marks for this question. If you do not like this question please leave it as for another one who wish to answer.

There are 2 check box groups 'main' & 'sub.

if user select '**Main_CheckBox_1**' from '**main**' need to show '**Sub_Checkbox_1_Main_1**' and '**Sub_Checkbox_2_Main_1**' from '*sub*'
and also if user select '**Main_CheckBox_2**' need to show '**Sub_Checkbox_1_Main_2**' & '**Sub_Checkbox_2_Main_2**'

```
<div id = "mainDiv" >   
    <input type="checkbox" name="main" value="main_1"><span>Main_CheckBox_1</span> <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="main" value="main_1"><span>Main_CheckBox_2</span><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="main" value="main_1"><span>Main_CheckBox_2</span><br/>
</div>

<div id = "subDiv" >    
    <input type="checkbox" name="sub" value="Sub_1_of_main_1"><span>Sub_Checkbox_1_Main_1</span> <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="sub" value="Sub_2_of_main_1"><span>Sub_Checkbox_2_Main_1</span><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="sub" value="Sub_1_of_main_2"><span>Sub_Checkbox_1_Main_2</span><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="sub" value="Sub_2_of_main_2"><span>Sub_Checkbox_2_Main_2</span><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="sub" value="Sub_1_of_main_3"><span>Sub_Checkbox_1_Main_3</span><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="sub" value="Sub_2_of_main_3"><span>Sub_Checkbox_2_Main_3</span><br/>
</div>
```

**1. how to identify which check box is selected from 'main' ?**

**2. how to show/hide check boxes in 'sub' depending on 'main' check boxes ?**

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Give all inputs with name main `input[name='main']` the trigger to act on change.  Then `this.value` will tell you which one in particular was changed.

2) Make a function that takes `this.value`as parameter and then toggle (hide/show) the two corresponding checkboxes and the next element ()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='main']").change(function() {
        showHide(this.value);
    });
});

function showHide (chkbx) {
     var k = "input[value='Sub_1_of_"+chkbx+"']";
     $(k).toggle(0);
     $(k).next().toggle(0);
     var k = "input[value='Sub_2_of_"+chkbx+"']";
     $(k).toggle(0);
     $(k).next().toggle(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be easier if you'd grouped your sub checkboxes like below. Use CSS to hide all groups during load. This would produce a lot more cleaner and readable DOM/code.

```js
$(function() {
    var $groups = $("#subDiv .group");
    $('#mainDiv :checkbox').on("change", function() {
        var index = parseInt($(this).val().slice(-1), 10) - 1;
        $groups.eq(index).toggle(this.checked).siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

```css
#subDiv .group {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "mainDiv" >   
    <input type="checkbox" name="main" value="main_1" /><span>Main_CheckBox_1</span> <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="main" value="main_2" /><span>Main_CheckBox_2</span><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="main" value="main_3" /><span>Main_CheckBox_3</span><br/>
</div>

<div id = "subDiv" >
    <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sub" value="Sub_1_of_main_1" /><span>Sub_Checkbox_1_Main_1</span> <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="sub" value="Sub_2_of_main_1" /><span>Sub_Checkbox_2_Main_1</span><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sub" value="Sub_1_of_main_2" /><span>Sub_Checkbox_1_Main_2</span><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="sub" value="Sub_2_of_main_2" /><span>Sub_Checkbox_2_Main_2</span><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="sub" value="Sub_1_of_main_3" /><span>Sub_Checkbox_1_Main_3</span><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="sub" value="Sub_2_of_main_3" /><span>Sub_Checkbox_2_Main_3</span><br/>
    </div>
</div>
```